# onSubmit not working inside react-bootstrap nav dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to fix this but ran out of ideas. This is my first react project.
I am trying to add a search input inside a nav dropdown. I am using react-bootstrap.
I know i am close to getting it working because if i remove the form and place it outside the dropdown eg placing it in header it works fine. So its something inside the dropdown thats causing an error. I narrowed it down to not submitting.

```
    <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
    <Navbar.Header> ...

    </Navbar.Header>

    <Navbar.Collapse>

      <Nav pullRight>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#" className="nav-item">
          Home
        </NavItem>
        <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Watches" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.3} className="nav-item">
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.term}
                onChange={this.onInputChange}
                onClick={this.onClickStopDismiss}
              />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </MenuItem>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
```

The handlers written inside the same tasteful component are below. The reason for the onClickStopDismiss added to the input is because when I select the search bar inside the dropdown it closed it before I could type. By adding this onClick to the search input it stopped the dropdown from closing.

The state is passed up into a parent component but its not relevant here because nothing is appearing inside the console.log before it gets lifted up into parent. So there is something preventing the submit button.

```
class NavMain extends Component {
  state = {
    term: ""
  };

  onInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ term: e.target.value });
  };

  onFormSubmit = e => {
    console.log(this.state.term);
    e.preventDefault();

    // call back function that will run when called from parent component
    this.props.onTermSubmit(this.state.term);
    this.setState({ term: "" });
  };

  onClickStopDismiss = e => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  };
```

Any ideas appreciated please. EDIT: no errors appearing in console.

[link here to image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28lv0.jpg)

Comment: Does it detect a click if you add a handler directly to the button? ie: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={onSubmitClick}/>`

Comment: Good point i forgot to check that. Yes it console logs clicked if i add onClick to the onClick={() => console.log("submit")} to the button. I will try run form that way  1 sec

Comment: WOO thank you all it works now.

So instead of using onSubmit on the form. I used onClick=this.buttonFormSubmitClicked on the form button.

Then in buttonFormSubmitClicked i used the code from the form submit to change state and lift up state. thanks all thank you

now trying to work out how to award answer =/

Comment: Glad it helped! I made an answer so people can more easily see what fixed your problem

Answer (score 1):

As a work-around you could detect a submit event by adding a click handler directly to the `input` element and skip the using forms in this particular case.

```
<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
<Navbar.Header> ...

</Navbar.Header>

<Navbar.Collapse>

  <Nav pullRight>
    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#" className="nav-item">
      Home
    </NavItem>
    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Watches" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
      <MenuItem eventKey={3.3} className="nav-item">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
          onClick={this.onClickStopDismiss}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={onSubmit} />
      </MenuItem>
    </NavDropdown>
  </Nav>
</Navbar.Collapse>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `e.target.value` to a variable before passing it to `setState()`.

```
onInputChange = e => {
  let event = e.target.value;
  this.setState({ term: event })
}
```

This happens because `setState()` is asynchronous so by the time it's executed, your `e.target.value` reference might or might not exist.

Comment: Hello Giogrio  I tried making the change and it still does not work.
The form outside the dropdown works with your code and my old code but the form inside the nav dropdown does not register the submit.

I even made it simpler to test. The onFormSubmit now has a console.log('clicked') 
so everytime i hit submit it should console log clicked

the form outside the nav maks the console display clicked but the console inside the drop down does nothing. So without even changing state the submit button not firing.